# Cannot update value to checkbox Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, checkbox

I'm trying to update my checkbox such as if patientPHistory is "Yes", Patient checkbox will be a tick. I am able to retrieve all values from database except these two.
However there are some problems such as when both patientPHistory and patientPPhysical are "Yes" and both checkbox will tick but when only one of patientPHistory or patientPPhysical is a "Yes" in the database, all checkboxes will not tick.

For the sample database image, its in this link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMAd3.jpg

For instance, B.K.K will make both checkboxes checked but B.K.Z.W and T.Y.Y would not even though there is a "Yes".

```
private CheckBox History, Physical;

    private void RetrieveDataFromDatabase(String res)
{
    patientPHistory = "";
    patientPPhysical = "";
    myContext = this;
    patientDB = new PatientDB(myContext);
    patientDB.open();

    Cursor patientCursor;

    patientCursor = patientDB.retrieveAllBasedOnInitials(res);

    if(patientCursor!=null && patientCursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        patientCursor.moveToFirst();
        do 
        {
            patientCursor.getString(patientDB.COLUMN_KEY_ID); // + " " + 
            patientInitials = patientCursor.getString(patientDB.COLUMN_INITIALS_ID);
            patientDate = patientCursor.getString(patientDB.COLUMN_DATE_ID);
            patientSite = patientCursor.getString(patientDB.COLUMN_SITE_ID);
            patientWard = patientCursor.getString(patientDB.COLUMN_WARD_ID);
            patientPHistory = patientCursor.getString(patientDB.COLUMN_PERF_HISTORY_ID);
            patientPPhysical = patientCursor.getString(patientDB.COLUMN_PERF_PHYSICAL_ID);
            Log.i("ward", patientWard);
            Log.i("date", patientDate);
            Log.i("site", patientSite);
            Log.i("history", patientPHistory);
            Log.i("physical", patientPPhysical);

            //SET THEM
            DateOfDiagnosis.setText(patientDate);
            Ward.setText(patientWard);

            if (patientPHistory.contains("Yes"))
            {
                History.setChecked(true);
            }
            else if (patientPHistory.contains("No"))
            {
                History.setChecked(false);
            }

            if (patientPPhysical.contains("Yes"))
            {
                Physical.setChecked(true);
            }
            else if (patientPPhysical.contains("No"))
            {
                Physical.setChecked(false);
            }

            //Set to spinner
            List<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            newlist.add(patientSite);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newlist);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            SpinnerSite.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        } 
        while (patientCursor.moveToNext()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: don't you think it should be "patientPPhysical.equals("NO")" in your condition?

Comment: I think you have not initialised `History`. You have to do something like this `Hitory = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.historyid);` before accessing it

Comment: Vishwas, I tried .matches .equals and .contains - all doesn't work if both my data contains one yes

Comment: Abhishek, i am able to check if both physical and history are yes but not when one of them is a yes

Comment: In case of your issues scenario, what does the below log prints?
`Log.i("history", patientPHistory);
Log.i("physical", patientPPhysical);`

Comment: Rajeev, for B.K.K history and physical are both "Yes" but for B.K.Z.W both are "No"

Comment: So there is your problem Spencer. Your database is returning wrong information. Mostly your input to the database was wrong. For B.K.Z.W it should have been "Yes" & "No".

Answer (score 0):

If you have only yes or no values then use only else instead of else if 
i.e.

```
if (patientPHistory.contains("Yes"))
            {
                History.setChecked(true);
                Log.i("checked or not","yes");
            }
            else
            {
                History.setChecked(false);
                Log.i("checked or not","no");
            }
```

Comment: Works only when both physical and history are yes but not when one of them is a yes and one of them is a no

Comment: did you check your logs are you sure logs giving you right data when one of them is a yes and one of them is a no

Answer (score 0):

I realized that my cursor has two of the same entity which led to this error, thanks for helping it was my carelessness.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the `adapter` code be outside the `do-while` loop? This portion `//Set to spinner
            List<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
            newlist.add(patientSite);
            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, newlist);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            SpinnerSite.setAdapter(dataAdapter);`